# Algolia facet attribute multiple values

Tags: objective-c, facet, algolia

I have an attribute "bodyType" and it has multiple values like sedan, suv, coupe etc. If I want to search for sedan I apply the facetFilters like [@"bodytype:sedan"] and it works fine but if I want to see both sedan and suv then I do [@"bodyType:sedan", @"bodyType:suv"] and it returns zero results. I am using the objective c ios sdk.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show the rest of your code that you are using to search.

Comment: ASRemoteIndex *indexForClient = [self getIndex:BASIC_INDEX_NAME];
    ASQuery *newQuery = [[ASQuery alloc] init];
    [newQuery setHitsPerPage:[HITS_PER_PAGE integerValue]];
    [newQuery setPage:pageNumber];
    if (filtersString) {
        [newQuery setFilters:filtersString];
    }
    if (tagFilters) {
        [newQuery setFullTextQuery:tagFilters];
    }
    if ([facetFilterArray count]) {
        [newQuery setFacetFilters:facetFilterArray];
    }

Comment: Please edit your initial question with properly formatted code :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `facetFilters`, top-level filters are implicitly conjunctive (i.e. combined with an `AND` operator). This is why you are seeing no results: the intersection of both results sets is empty.

To supply disjunctive filters (`OR` operator), use a nested array, as explained in the [documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-client/swift/parameters/facetFilters/):

`[["bodyType:sedan", "bodyType:suv"]]`

Using `filters` with `bodyType:sedan OR bodyType:suv` works as well.

Answer (score 1):

Had a quick look at the documentation, and it sounds like `filters` property will do what you need:

```
/**
 * Filter the query with numeric, facet or/and tag filters. The syntax is a SQL like syntax, you can use the OR and AND keywords.
 * The syntax for the underlying numeric, facet and tag filters is the same than in the other filters:
 * available=1 AND (category:Book OR NOT category:Ebook) AND public
 * date: 1441745506 TO 1441755506 AND inStock > 0 AND author:"John Doe"
 * The list of keywords is:
 * OR: create a disjunctive filter between two filters.
 * AND: create a conjunctive filter between two filters.
 * TO: used to specify a range for a numeric filter.
 * NOT: used to negate a filter. The syntax with the ‘-‘ isn’t allowed.
 */
@property (nonatomic) NSString             *filters;
```

As an example:

```
NSString *filterString = @"bodyType:sedan OR bodyType:suv";

ASRemoteIndex *indexForClient = [self getIndex:BASIC_INDEX_NAME]; 
ASQuery *newQuery = [[ASQuery alloc] init]; 
[newQuery setHitsPerPage:[HITS_PER_PAGE integerValue]]; 
[newQuery setPage:pageNumber]; 

if (filtersString) { 
    [newQuery setFilters:filtersString]; 
}

if (tagFilters) { 
    [newQuery setFullTextQuery:tagFilters]; 
} 

if (filterString.length) { 
    [newQuery setFilters:filterString]; 
}
```

Comment: With filters it do works but I am trying to do it with facetFilters. I believe we can check for multiple values for the same attribute. cant we?

Comment: I think the issue is that facetFilters inherently use AND logic. i.e. you're filtering an object that has both a body type of 'suv' AND 'sedan', hence the zero results. As far as I'm aware, there's no way to change that. `filters` simply gives you a lot more room to move.